# Bootstrap navbar reacting only to icons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I've just started out with webdev and I have a problem with my navbar. It only sends you to the corresponding sub-site when clicked directly on the icon or the writing. I'd like it to behave like a button as a whole. I have spent a good few hours searching the net and looking at the problem from different angles but i still can't find a solution.  [Here's the navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWB23.png)

```css
.nav-side-menu {
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
    background-color: #222;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 100%;
    color: #e1ffff;
}

.nav-side-menu .brand {
    background-color: #23282e;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: block;
}

.nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
    display: none;
    background-color: #222;
    color: #222;
}

.nav-side-menu ul,
.nav-side-menu li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: center;
  /*    
    .collapsed{
       .arrow:before{
                 font-family: FontAwesome;
                 content: "\f053";
                 display: inline-block;
                 padding-left:10px;
                 padding-right: 10px;
                 vertical-align: middle;
                 float:right;
            }
     }
*/
}

.nav-side-menu ul :not(collapsed) .arrow:before,
.nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f078";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
}

.nav-side-menu ul .active,
.nav-side-menu li .active {
    border-left: 3px solid #00ACDD;
    background-color: #4f5b69;
}

.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active {
    color: #00ACDD;
}

.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active a,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active a {
    color: #00ACDD;
}

.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li {
    background-color: #181c20;
    border: none;
    line-height: 28px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:hover,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #020203;
}

.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:before,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f105";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav-side-menu li {
    padding-left: 0px;
    border-left: 3px solid #2e353d;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-side-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e1ffff;
}

.nav-side-menu li a i {
    vertical-align: center;
}

.nav-side-menu li:hover {
    border-left: 3px solid #00ACDD;
    background-color: #000000;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.nav-side-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
  
.nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 10 !important;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #222;
    color: #00ACDD;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
  
.brand {
    text-align: center !important;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    line-height: 50px !important;
}
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
.nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
    display: block;
}
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url(graphics/clouds5.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}

.navbar-icon {
    font-size:36px;
    margin-top:10%;
}
    
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .topnavbutton-mobile{
        padding-left: 0px;
        border-left: 3px solid #2e353d;
        border-top: 1px solid #00ACDD;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans">
</head>

<div class="nav-side-menu">
    <img src="graphics/Icon.png" style="width:40px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto"> 
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>
        <div class="menu-list">
            <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
                <li class="topnavbutton-mobile">
                 <a href="index.html">
                   <i class="fa fa-home navbar-icon"></i>
                   <h6 style="padding-top:0px;margin-top:0px;padding-bottom:10px">PLACEHOLDER</h6>
                   </a>
                </li>
                <li class="topnavbutton-mobile">
                   <a href="#">
                   <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart navbar-icon"></i>
                   <h6 style="padding-top:0px;margin-top:0px;padding-bottom:10px">PLACEHOLDER</h6>
                   </a>
                </li>
                <li class="topnavbutton-mobile">
                   <a href="signup.html">
                   <i class="fa fa-user-o navbar-icon"></i>
                   <h6 style="padding-top:0px;margin-top:0px;padding-bottom:10px">PLACEHOLDER</h6>
                   </a>
                </li>
                <li class="topnavbutton-mobile">
                   <a href="builder.html">
                   <i class="fa fa-wrench navbar-icon"></i>
                   <h6 style="padding-top:0px;margin-top:0px;padding-bottom:10px">PLACEHOLDER</h6>
                   </a>
                </li>
                <li class="topnavbutton-mobile">
                   <a href="#">
                   <i class="fa fa-envelope-o navbar-icon"></i>
                   <h6 style="padding-top:0px;margin-top:0px;padding-bottom:10px">PLACEHOLDER</h6>
                   </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to make icon as button? or you want all icons to look like a single button?

Comment: What do you mean by "I'd like it to behave like a button as a whole."?

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:block` to your `<a>` tags in CSS or with inline style attitude.

Comment: That worked. It messed up some of the positioning but I sorted it out. Thanks a lot.